# How can I convert password string to Base64 string before sending form to backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a sample registration form, it works properly for most cases, but when I try to register new user with password "U8$&#6G#CBj" I'm getting an exception **"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"**
My idea is to convert password to Base64 format before sending it to backend and on backend convert it back. How can I do it?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
     {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
           @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
           <div class="col-md-10">
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
           <div class="col-md-10">
              @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
              <div class="checkbox">
                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
              <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
           </div>
        </div>
        <p>
           @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
        </p>
        @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality *@
        <p>
           @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
        </p>
     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript

Comment: thanks for fast reply, I'll try it

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client) will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help of [Alexei Levenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477420/alexei-levenkov) for frontend part and [Vidhyadhar Galande](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5628850/vidhyadhar-galande) for backend I solved my problem here is the code:
on View to form I have added this javascript function on submit event

```
function encode(){
        $('#Password').val(btoa($('#Password').val()));
        $('#ConfirmPassword').val(btoa($('#ConfirmPassword').val()));
    }
```

and on backend decode strings back:

```
private string DecodeFromBase64(string inputBas64)
{
    var base64EncodedBytesPassword = System.Convert.FromBase64String(model.Password);
    string password = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytesPassword);
    return password;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

1) base64(Encode/decode)

```
 public static string base64Encode(string sData) // Encode
 {
   try
    {
       byte[] encData_byte = new byte[sData.Length];
       encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sData);
       string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte);
       return encodedData;
    }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw new Exception("Error in base64Encode" + ex.Message);
   }
 }

public static string base64Decode(string sData) //Decode
 {
    try
    {
      var encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
      System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();
      byte[] todecodeByte = Convert.FromBase64String(sData);
      int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecodeByte, 0, todecodeByte.Length);
      [] decodedChar = new char[charCount];
      utf8Decode.GetChars(todecodeByte, 0, todecodeByte.Length, decodedChar, 0);
      string result = new String(decodedChar);
      return result;
   }
  catch (Exception ex)
   {
      throw new Exception("Error in base64Decode" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

> 2) EncodePasswordMd5

```
 public static string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt) //encrypt password
   {
      byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
      byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);
      byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
      System.Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
      System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
      HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
      byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
      //return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
      return EncodePasswordMd5(Convert.ToBase64String(inArray));
   }
  public static string EncodePasswordMd5(string pass) //Encrypt using MD5
   {
      Byte[] originalBytes;
      Byte[] encodedBytes;
      MD5 md5;
      //Instantiate MD5CryptoServiceProvider, get bytes for original password and compute hash (encoded password)
      md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
      originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(pass);
      encodedBytes = md5.ComputeHash(originalBytes);
      //Convert encoded bytes back to a 'readable' string
      return BitConverter.ToString(encodedBytes);
  }
```

> @Using Namespace

```
  using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
```

Comment: on backend this is useful, but I need to convert string on frontend site